# How to align equation number to come at the bottom?

Tags: equations

How can I align the equation number to come at the bottom instead of the centre? I tried using aligned[b] but it does not affect!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}[b]
        \begin{tabular}{clr}
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

        \end{tabular}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{center}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're using `amsmath`, so if you always want the tag on the last line in a multi-line/single number environment (`split`, `aligned`, and similar), you can specify the `tbtags` option: `\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}`.  See the user manual for details and other possibilities: `texdoc amsldoc`.

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}[b]
        \begin{tabular}[b]{clr} %%%%% <-----------
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}}$,
            &
            $\mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}$, \\

        \end{tabular}
        \end{aligned}
        \end{equation}
    \end{center}

    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The outer `aligned` isn't doing anything here. And I believe it would be better to use an `array` rather than a `tabular` with `$...$`.

Comment: @campa, you are right. I focused only on the issue raised by OP.

Answer (score 2):

As you don't seem to align whatever, the `aligned` environment is unnecessary. Also the content of `equation`  is automatically centred. Last, for math mode, it's simpler to use `array`. So I propose this simplified code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french,USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[mmddyyyy]{datetime}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{array}[b]{clr}
          \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}} ,
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}} ,
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}} , \\
         \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}} ,
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}},
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}, \\
        \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd (X, Y)}{P \lhd X}},
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \lhd \langle X \rangle _Y}{P \lhd X}},
        & \mathrm{\dfrac{P \models Q \stackrel{K}{\leftrightarrow} P \mbox(, ) P \lhd \{X\}_K} {P \lhd X}}, \end{array}
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]